# How to hide button after clicked (TypeScript)

Tags: angular, typescript

**Html**

```
<button mat-icon-button matTooltip="hi" *ngIf="isValid" (click)="hi(x, y)">
```

---

**ts**

```
isValid: boolean = false;

hi(x,y){
  this.isValid
}
```

I'm so stuck I just started.

I want to hide the button after clicked.

Comment: Please share the actual code instead of images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is:

```
isValid: boolean = true;

hi(x,y) {
  this.isValid = false;
}
```

Comment: Because your initialize isValid with false value. I updated my answer, set it to true to get the button visible.